# Parent theme's custom shortcode not working in child theme

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am a wordpress beginner. I created a custom function in functions.php of my main theme and add shortcode of that function. Now I am using the shortcode on a page of my main theme, its working fine.

Now I made a child theme, and now I am using the same shortcode on one of my pages of child theme. But its not working, it simply show shortcode at page like text.

What am I Missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it guys by just putting a blank function.php in child's theme folder. Hope it will help somebody.